Subtracting two lists with the same structure but getting this error: 'non-numeric argument to binary operator'
I have these sample lists and I am trying to subtract them:
> str(list1)
List of 3
 $ 1:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:13] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ 2001: num [1:13] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  ..$ 2002: num [1:13] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 ...
 $ 2:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:13] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
  ..$ 2001: num [1:13] 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
  ..$ 2002: num [1:13] 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 ...
 $ 3:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:13] 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 ...
  ..$ 2001: num [1:13] 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 ...
  ..$ 2002: num [1:13] 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 ...

> str(list2)
List of 3
 $ 1:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:13] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ 2001: num [1:13] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ 2002: num [1:13] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ 2:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:13] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ 2001: num [1:13] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ 2002: num [1:13] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ 3:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:13] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
  ..$ 2001: num [1:13] 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
  ..$ 2002: num [1:13] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...

But when I try to subtract these two lists,
diff <- list1 - list2

R is giving me this error:
Error in list1 - list2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

data
obtained with dput()
list1 <- list(`1` = list(`2000` = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5), `2001` = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10), `2002` = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15)), `2` = list(`2000` = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20), `2001` = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 25), `2002` = c(30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30)), `3` = list(`2000` = c(35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35), `2001` = c(40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40), `2002` = c(45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45)))

list2 <- list(`1` = list(`2000` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), `2001` = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), `2002` = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), `2` = list(`2000` = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), `2001` = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), `2002` = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6)), `3` = list(`2000` = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7), `2001` = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
), `2002` = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)))


What's you expected output? Do you really want to subtract years and months or just x?

Hi! I only want to subtract x. Thank you

Then try lapply(df$x - df2$x, rep, each=13)

Oh sorry about the confusion. But list 1 have different values by year and only list 2 has repeating values. I'll edit my post. Apologies for this

seems that you are repeating both. Also, better do computation on dataframes rather than lists. Also, in cae everything is numeric, just use recursions

You can try unlist + relist
> relist(unlist(list1) - unlist(list2), list1)
$`1`
$`1`$`2000`
 [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

$`1`$`2001`
 [1] 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8

$`1`$`2002`
 [1] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12


$`2`
$`2`$`2000`
 [1] 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16

$`2`$`2001`
 [1] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20

$`2`$`2002`
 [1] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24


$`3`
$`3`$`2000`
 [1] 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28

$`3`$`2001`
 [1] 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32

$`3`$`2002`
 [1] 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36


use recursion. Note that this works with data that is homogeneous: ie similar structure.
list_subtract <- function(x, y) if(is.atomic(x)) x - y else Map(list_subtract, x, y)
list_subtract(list1, list2)


this works with data! Thank youuuu so much!!!!!

You can easily handle this with arrays, which are essentially multidimensional matrices.
Example:
Two arrays,
> A1
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    3    3
[3,]    3    3

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    2    2

> A2
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    2    2

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1

subtracted.
> A1 - A2
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1

If your data is homogeneous (e.g., numeric), as it looks like, you can convert it into an array.
Here is an ad-hoc function to convert lists into arrays and vice versa,
> lstcnv <- \(x, to=c('array', 'list')) {
+   to <- match.arg(to)
+   if (identical(to, 'array')) {
+     list2array <- \(x) {
+       if (is.atomic(x[[1]])) {
+         simplify2array(x)
+       } else {
+         simplify2array(lapply(x, list2array))
+       } 
+     }
+     list2array(x)
+   } else {
+     array2list <- \(x) {
+       atl <- \(x) {
+         if (is.array(x) && length(dim(x)) > 2) {
+           lapply(seq_len(dim(x)[length(dim(x))]), 
+                  \(i) atl(apply(x, seq_len(length(dim(x)) - 1), `[`, i)))
+         } else {
+           x
+         }
+       }
+       rc_atl <- \(x) if (is.list(x)) lapply(x, rc_atl) else atl(x)
+       rc_atl(x)
+     }
+     array2list(x)
+   }
+ }

where x= is the object, and to= is the direction (can be abbreviated and defaults to 'array').
Using the function, you can do,
> res <- lstcnv(lstcnv(list1) - lstcnv(list2), 'l')

where
> str(res)
List of 3
 $ 1:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:13] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ 2001: num [1:13] 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
  ..$ 2002: num [1:13] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ 2:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:13] 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
  ..$ 2001: num [1:13] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
  ..$ 2002: num [1:13] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
 $ 3:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:13] 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 ...
  ..$ 2001: num [1:13] 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 ...
  ..$ 2002: num [1:13] 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 ...

Of course, instead of constantly converting back and forth, you can perform the calculations directly with arrays, which would also be more efficient.

if you are converting to array, use recursion eg: list2array <- function(x){   if(is.atomic(x[[1]])) simplify2array(x)   else simplify2array(lapply(x, list2array)) }

And then try something like list2array(rep(list(list(list(1:3,2:4), list(2:4,3:5))),3))

@Onyambu Thanks, looks neat but that's > 2 times slower, test list2array on replicate(1e4, list1$1, simplify=FALSE).

That is because the code is generic ie. try running list2array(rep(list(list(list(1:3,2:4), list(2:4,3:5))),3)) vs lstcnv(rep(list(list(list(1:3,2:4), list(2:4,3:5))),3)) and you will note that lstcnv gives incorrect results

@Onyambu Right, it's safer since it covers any list type, I've taken it up in the answer. Thanks! Just need to care fore the to='l' direction.

@Onyambu Should be solved, feel free to check.
